# How to accelerate a shell script for a mongoDB application?

Tags: json, mongodb, shell, parallel-processing, bigdata

I started shell scripting for my work, but I must admit I'm still far away from even being a rookie. Therefore I wanted to ask you for your help/advice.

I build a script for a big data application (taking the quick and dirty approach, patching stuff from the internet together) to recursively go through a folder structure and convert convert all XML files to JSON.

The status quo of my script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shell script to find out all the files under a directory and
#its subdirectories. This also takes into consideration those files
#or directories which have spaces or newlines in their names

cd /Users/q337498/Desktop/Archiv/2014/01/10

DIR="."

function list_files()
{
if !(test -d "$1")
then echo $1; return;
fi

cd "$1"
#echo; echo `pwd`:; #Display Directory name

for i in *
    do
        if test -d "$i"; then # if dictionary
            if [ "$(ls -A $i)" ]; then
                list_files "$i" #recursively list files
                cd ..
            else
               echo "$i is Empty"
            fi
        else
            java -jar /Users/q337498/Desktop/XML2JSON/SaxonEE9-5-1-4J/saxon9ee.jar -s:"$i" -xsl:/Users/q337498/Desktop/xsltjson-master/conf/xml-to-json.xsl -o:output/$(pwd)/${i%%[.]*}
#            if jsonlint /Users/q337498/Desktop/Archiv/2014/01/08/$(pwd)/${i%%[.]*} -q; then
#                echo "GOOD"
#            else
#                echo "NOT GOOD"
#            fi
#          echo ${i%%[.]*}
#          echo "$i"; #Display File name
        fi
    done
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then list_files .
    exit 0
fi

for i in $*
    do
        DIR="$1"
        list_files "$DIR"
        shift 1 #To read next directory/file namedone
    done
```

This code works, but the problem is that for 60000 files it takes up to 15 hours on a macbook pro with 16gb RAM and an 2.8 Ghz i7. And I need to convert 10 million files.

How do you think that I could accelerate the script? parallelize? take some commands out? What options do I have, and how would I actually implement them?

The files are ultimately going to end up in a MongoDB, so if someone knows a better way to convert xml to json and upload it to mongo his input is also welcome.

Cheers,

Dudu

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 immediate problems here:

1. You are invoking java once for each file, therefore incurring the JVM startup time for every file which is going to add up to a huge chunk of time.
2. You are running single threaded

So I would suggest that you:

- Write a Java program that does the directory traversal and does your transformation
- Benchmark the performance difference
- Try other Java libraries for doing the XML->JSON conversion https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Benchmark
- If necessary for performance, add multi-threading to your application using java.util.concurrent.